# Filter price according to Maximum Price of Product

Tags: views

I am using better exposed filters(https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) and have created a price filter and the range I have selected is 0 to 2000.But I want the maximum limit of the price filter to be the maximum price of the product on that page(I have multiple pages with different products).

Is there a way to do it using views?

Answer (score 1):

In view, add sort criteria for price filter i.e. Sort descending.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this and add additional conditions based on your page count:-

```
/**
* Implements hook_js_alter().
*/
function hook_js_alter(&$javascript) {

 $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
 $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'commerce_product')
 ->entityCondition('bundle', 'product') // replace with your bundle
 ->propertyCondition('type', 'product') // replace with your type
 ->fieldOrderBy('commerce_price','amount','DESC');
 $result = $query->execute();

 // Get the commerce product id for the max price
 reset($result['commerce_product']);
 $product_id = key($result['commerce_product']);
 $product =  commerce_product_load($product_id);

 $price = commerce_product_calculate_sell_price($product);
 $price = $price['amount']/100;


$settings = $javascript['settings']['data'];

foreach ($settings as $key => $value) {
  if (isset($settings[$key]['better_exposed_filters']['slider_options']['commerce_price_amount']['max'])) {
    $settings[$key]['better_exposed_filters']['slider_options']['commerce_price_amount']['max'] = $price;
  }
}

$javascript['settings']['data'] = $settings;
}
```

Comment: js alter is cool but isn't there a way of doing it using views?

Comment: Not that i know of. Its a BEF module feature and they have added these options as javascript options.